# Different content at qtip2 with if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make tooltip with image content always show on page load but there is if condition that make the tooltip will appear with different image.
The setup is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var warna = "";

    if(warna=="1")
     {
        {$('area').qtip({
        content: {
            text: '<img src="dist/img/Green-Circle-Button-90786.gif"  height="20" width="20"/>'
        },
        position: {
             my: 'bottom center', 
             at: 'top center'
        },
        style: {
                classes: 'qtip-tipsy'
            },
            show: {
                 solo: false,
                 ready: true, // Show when ready (page load)
                }
            },
            hide: {
                event: false
            }
        });
     }
     else
     {
        $('area').qtip({
        content: {
            text: '<img src="dist/img/Red-Circle-Button-90782.gif"  height="20" width="20"/>'
        },
        position: {
             my: 'bottom center',  
             at: 'top center' 
        },
        style: {
                classes: 'qtip-tipsy'
            },
            show: {
                 solo: false,
                 ready: true // Show when ready (page load)
            },
            hide: {
                event: false
            }
        });
     }

});
```

The problem is, tooltip always appear in else condition even value of warna == 1. Is there any solution?

Comment: How can `warna=='1'` when you just declared it as `''`? Something is missing here.

Comment: the value of warna will get from query of database that not included here @charlietfl.